# Symfony rewrite .htaccess

Tags: symfony, mod-rewrite

After putting my site on a sever I would like my domain name to be redirected to my homepage

For example, I want to redirect the domain `example.com` to `example.com/home`.

Help me. This is my file .htaccess

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [QSA,L]
IfModule
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this :

```
Redirect / http://www.example.com/home
```

Hope that helps.